# Why MariaDB Galera Cluster only supports the InnoDB/XtraDB storage engine

Tags: innodb, mariadb, galera

Now i'm find and config mariadb galera cluster? But i don't know why mariadb galera cluster only support InnoDB.

Pls advice to fix it.

Thanks alots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is essentially no reason to support any engine other than InnoDB.  You *can* have MyISAM or MEMORY tables, but not get the synchronized replication to the other nodes.

Only with InnoDB, can the synchronous replication be achieved.  I feel certain that MyISAM and MEMORY will never be fully supported.  However, other transaction-safe engines (Tokudb?) might some day.

Why do you want some other engine?  Perhaps we can help you achieve the *real* goal by some other means.

Addenda...

Synchronous replication, the way Galera implemented, requires being able to `ROLLBACK` even at `COMMIT`.  Otherwise, duplicate keys would be an unsolvable problem when allowing writes to all nodes.

An aside...  NDB takes a radically different approach -- "eventual consistency", wherein duplicate keys can get into the system, but the user has to provide an algorithm for fixing the mess.

InnoDB on a single machine checks as the statements within the transaction are being performed.  Galera does not.  It is "optimistic" -- transactions are performed without checking the other nodes until the `COMMIT`.  This provided performance because of only a single roundtrip to each other node.  (Hence, "medium sized" transactions are optimal.)

MyISAM has no way to do `ROLLBACK`; it depends on locking table up front.  Locking tables on another node would be very clumsy and inefficient.

Galera can work efficiently even in a WAN -- again because of the single action at `COMMIT`.

Comment: Thanks your answer, because i want know why maria galera cluster cannot support Myisam, :)

Comment: Just a curiosity?  Not "I insist on using MyISAM; why won't Galera supprt it"?  If you said the latter, then I would ask why you insist on MyISAM.  If you said "its faster"; I would say "in what cases"?  If you said it's smaller, I would say "let's look for ways to shrink your datatypes, add normalization, etc."  I'll add a little more in a minute.

Comment: added more details on Galera transactions versus others.

Comment: Galera isn't synchronous replication.

Comment: @akuzminsky - Technically, Galera is not fully asynchronous.  But if you add [_code for Critical Reads_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/galera#critical_reads) , it is effectively synchronous.

Comment: It was hinted to in the answer, but not explicitly stated: Galera can only work on engines that fully support transactions. Hence MyISAM is out of luck, but maybe Aria engine will come into scope once MardiaDB team make it fully transactional.